# getopt does not order arguments in Windows

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, getopt

It seems that `getopt` behaves differently in Windows than in Linux. Windows requires a strict ordering of parameters while in Linux I can put the arguments in any order. Consider a program `test` which uses `getopt` compiled for Linux (gcc) and Windows (MinGW) and take this command line for example:

```
test file1.bin file2.bin -o output.txt
```

Executing this command in **Linux** would correctly parse `-o output.txt` as an option(+parameter) regardless of where I put `-o output.txt`. It could be between `file1.bin` and `file2.bin` as well and `getopt` parsing would still work correctly since it sorts the arguments by putting the optional ones infront of the mandatories.

Executing this command in **Windows** however results in incorrect parsing, giving me a wrong index in `optind` variable. It seems that the exact same code when compiled in Windows does not do the sorting part for me. Why is this, can we workaround this?

Comment: GNU `getopt()` permutes the arguments (so options can occur after non-option arguments) by default.  Standard POSIX `getopt()` does not allow that.  You can make GNU `getopt()` conform by exporting `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`.  Check the manual for MinGW `getopt()`, or the Microsoft implementation of it.  It probably doesn't do the permutation.  You'll then need to arrange to use a copy of the GNU `getopt()` – maybe by getting the source, compiling it, and including it in your build process.  Or you'll have to decide that the GNU extension isn't portable and therefore shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: See the manual for GNU [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt).

Comment: *Executing this command in **Linux** would correctly parse -o output.txt as an option*  That's a non-standard, non-portable GNU extension to [POSIX standard argument parsing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).  The Linux parsing is not "correct".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification that the sorting is not POSIX standard.

Comment: Please make this an answer and mark it to help others.

Comment: If @JonathanLeffler could move his comment to an answer I will mark it as solved. Otherwise I will write my own answer and cite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring my comments to an answer as requested.*</sup>

GNU [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) permutes the arguments (so options can occur after non-option arguments) by default. Standard POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) does not allow that. You can make GNU `getopt()` conform to POSIX by exporting the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`, or by starting the `options` argument with a `+` symbol.

Check the manual (or source) for MinGW [`getopt()`](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/misc/getopt.c), or the Microsoft implementation of it. Given what you see, it probably doesn't do the permutation.  However, the linked source code does support permutation — you'll need to investigate what goes on there.

If you decide to use GNU `getopt()`, you'll need to get a copy of the GNU `getopt()` source code (maybe from GitHub [`getopt.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/getopt.c)) and include it in your build process.  If you use that, you'll also need [`ansidecl.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/include/ansidecl.h) and [`getopt.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/include/getopt.h) at minimum and you will need to tweak the configuration appropriately.

Or you'll have to decide that the GNU extension of permuting options isn't portable and therefore shouldn't be used at all.